# can't get button added after div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a button if the .mbs div is found or if more === undefined. I've got:

JS

```
        if ($((uCW).find('.mbs')).length) {uCW.prepend(button);}
        if (more === undefined) {uCW.prepend(button);}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mbs _6m6 _2cnj _5s6c"><a href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fslate.com%2Fculture%2F2020%2F04%2Firrfan-khan-bollywood-roles-death.html%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0iQedXnjD8C89RemI1DvmaaK6Qos79obbZbC03ld6z54OtMDWcZUZqrPI&amp;h=AT0CEUjM2oNg252XVp4MiK8PDHqO5JrSrnEQ0baNJ3E-LFHqJBf9e6q9cqjgOfufDYOkGj8dybDGS2IllCPXsXTQeJvJWAzxhJHPRDrYthCGhuGwyrIzcAgEWdYfple-Vwgp_5-fTnG5QDEVm8eFk1Tg01W_vjvV5V8jYUqo8tY" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" data-lynx-mode="asynclazy">If You Only Know Irrfan Khan From Slumdog Millionaire, You’re Missing Out on One of Our Greatest Actors</a></div>
```

`if (more === undefined) {uCW.prepend(button);}` works fine, but I'm not getting the button after mbs. No errors.

Comment: what is `more`? Can you post a snippet that showcases your issue?

Comment: works fine, what's mean? It's working properly

Comment: hmmm ... if the code looks right to you guys, then I'm thinking it must be something with the HTML. This could be a different question ... I'll play with it